# conditional operator possible in POJO class using annotations?

Tags: spring-boot

POJO Class:

```
        @Component
    public class Device {
        @JsonAlias("is5G") 
        private String deviceType;
        }
```

if devicetype is "4G" then "is5G" should be mapped with "N" else "Y". Possible to achieve this in POJO class using annotations?

Comment: Do you mean if it's possible to serialize to Json with this condition? Or when you set this field it will auto set another field to 'N' or 'Y', it's better to ask your question more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a custom converter

```
@JsonSerialize(converter = SerializeConverter.class)
@JsonDeserialize(converter = DeserializeConverter.class)
@JsonAlias("is5G") 
private String deviceType;
```

Serialize

```
public class SerializeConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {

  @Override
  public String convert(String value) {
      return value != null && value.equals("is5G") ? "Y" : "N";
  }
}
```

Deserialize

```
public class DeserializeConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {

  @Override
  public String convert(String value) {
      return value.equals("Y") ? "is5G" : null // or another value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Thank you